# React hook form returning undefined on submit

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, undefined

I am getting an undefined value after submitting a form with some text fields. I am quite stumped on this issue so I have provided some code below. I am using React Hook Form 7.11.1 Thank you for your help!

```
const FormInput = ({ name, label, required, defaultValue, InputProps }) => {
  const { control } = useFormContext;
  return (
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
      <Controller
        render={() => (
          <TextField
            control={control}
            fullWidth
            name={name}
            label={label}
            required={required}
            defaultValue={defaultValue}
            InputProps={InputProps}
          ></TextField>
        )}
      />
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

```
<FormProvider {...methods}>
        <form
          onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit((data) =>
            setShippingData({ ...data })
          )}
        >
          <Typography variant="h6">Billing Address</Typography>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <FormInput required name={"firstName"} label={"First Name"} />
            <FormInput required name={"lastName"} label={"Last Name"} />
            <FormInput required name={"address"} label={"Billing Address"} />
            <FormInput required name={"email"} label={"Email"} />
            <FormInput required name={"city"} label={"City"} />
            <FormInput required name={"zip"} label={"Postal Code"} />
</Form
```

Comment: hi, try using `onSubmit={(e) => console.log(e.target[0].value}` to make sure you actually receiving the values from form.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue in line 2 of 1st code snippet it should be

```
const { control } = useFormContext();
```

Also, `control` should be passed as props to `Controller` instead of `TextField`.  Refer [this](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller).